Girl Chased By A Teenage Street Gang From A Restaurant To The Subway
I saw this movie 3 - 8 years ago at my home. I can't remember the whole movie but the movie is from the United States in NYC or something and its from 2000-2010.
Movie info: Drama/Horror
What the movie is about:
There is a scene when this emo rebellious teen girl is talking with this blonde mature women in the diner/restaurant. I can't remember what they where talking about but the girl looks out the windows and she sees a gang is around the same age as her but demonic. Then she runs away to the subway where the gang follows her and the woman tries to help her by following too. This gang has some kind of whip and they use it to kill the girl and they have some kind of demonic flying creatures above them.
Main Actors: Mature woman has a shoulder-lenght blonde hair and she was average body build and the girl had short black hair and slim body build.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Sounds like Bless the Child (2000). At one point Maggie (played by Kim Bassinger who is a mature blonde with shoulder length hair) meets up with a young street girl named Cheri (  played by a goth Christina Ricci) at a diner who is later chased by a gang of devil worshiping street thugs.
This clip shows the meeting at the diner just before the gang starts chasing Cheri:



And the chase:



Synopsis:

Cody, a little girl abandoned by her mother and raised by a nurse, is kidnapped. The girl's guardian, aided by an FBI agent, learn that Cody has supernatural abilities and the abductees are a Satanic cult wanting to harness her abilities.


@GilgameshJajan If this is correct, don't forget to click on the check mark next to the answer. This resolves the question.
